# Is $f$ integrable, in the Darboux sense, on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad &x=0,\\
x\sin x,&x>0,
\end{cases}
$$
integrable, in the Darboux sense, on $[0,1]$?

I know the Darboux integral has to do with the upper sum and lower sum resulting in an equivalence between them. But I'm just a bit confused on how the partition is chosen?

Comment: Every continuous function on a closed, bounded interval is Darboux integrable.  You can use uniform continuity to prove this.